# Can one processing file be used for three forms of varying destination addresses?

Tags: php, xhtml

I'm working on a site which has three contact forms. All forms collect basic information name, email, comment..

My question is that can i use one php file (e.g. send-mail.php) to handle the sending of mail for all three forms even though the $emailto address of each form is different? If yes how do i achievce this? Or do i need one separate file for each form?

```
$emailTo = 'youremail@yoursite.com'; 
$body = "Name: $name \n\nEmail: $email \n\nSubject: $enquiry";
$headers = 'From: My Site <'.$emailTo.'>' . "\r\n" . 'Reply-To: ' . $email;

mail($emailTo, $subject, $body, $headers);
$emailSent = true;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can.  You need to somehow be able to differentiate the forms, and you can do so with a hidden form field on each contact page:

```
<form method = 'post' action = 'send-mail.php'>
    <input type = 'hidden' name = 'formID' id = 'formID' value = '1'>
```

Then just check against this type to determine what the to email address should be.

```
<?php
    if($_POST['formID'] == 1)
        $emailTo = "me@me.com";
    else if($_POST['formID'] == 2)
        $emailTo = "you@you.com";

   // ...

    mail($emailTo, $subject, $body, $headers);
?>
```

Comment: Just to add that whatever you do, don't put the 'email to' address as a hidden field element. An ID (as suggested here) is much better, otherwise anyone can submit your form to any email address they want by altering the value sent for the hidden element.